# How not to ignore blank lines in a web browser control?

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I want to display an HTML document in a web browser control but all blank lines are ignored. The blank lines are present in the document and are also displayed by other browsers such as Chrome (see screenshot).

I read the document via `File.ReadAllText()` into a string and pass it to the control:

```
public void SetWebBrowserContent(string html)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank");
    if (webBrowser1.Document != null)
    {
        webBrowser1.Document.Write(string.Empty);
    }
    webBrowser1.DocumentText = html;
}
```

However, all blank lines are ignored by the web browser control (see screenshots). How can I display them?

[Webbrowser control Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSAqc.png)

[Chrome Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6gqB.png)

HTML Snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html ><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta charset="UTF-8" /><title></title><meta name="Generator" content="PowerTools for Open XML" /><style>span { white-space: pre-wrap; }
h1.pt-Heading1 {
    margin-top: 12pt;
    line-height: 107.9%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-family: 'Calibri Light', 'sans-serif';
    font-size: 16pt;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
span.pt-DefaultParagraphFont {
    color: #2F5496;
    font-family: 'Calibri Light', 'sans-serif';
    font-size: 16pt;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
p.pt-Normal {
    line-height: 107.9%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 11pt;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
span.pt-000000 {
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
p.pt-NormalWeb {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: justify;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Open Sans;
    font-size: 10.5pt;
    line-height: 108%;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
span.pt-DefaultParagraphFont-000001 {
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Open Sans;
    font-size: 10.5pt;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
span.pt-000002 {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 10.5pt;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body { margin: 1cm auto; max-width: 20cm; padding: 0; }</style>
</head>

<body>
<div>
<h1 dir="ltr" class="pt-Heading1"><span class="pt-DefaultParagraphFont">Heading</span></h1>
<p dir="ltr" class="pt-Normal"><span xml:space="preserve" class="pt-000000"> </span></p>
<p dir="ltr" class="pt-NormalWeb"><span class="pt-DefaultParagraphFont-000001">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vulputate sed neque eget faucibus. Orci varius natoque penatibus et
magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nulla posuere porttitor elementum. Donec sem
tellus, condimentum non congue vel, fermentum nec velit. Donec vestibulum malesuada placerat. Duis
rhoncus lorem ligula, quis molestie lectus laoreet eget. Vivamus finibus lacinia elit, ut sagittis magna
dignissim id. Praesent nisi lorem, pharetra non feugiat a, elementum sit amet urna. Nulla est velit,
pharetra quis lacus vestibulum, faucibus laoreet elit. Praesent dignissim gravida urna sed tempor.
Suspendisse fringilla, purus eget ullamcorper pharetra, dui turpis maximus mauris, eu aliquet orci felis
a elit. Vestibulum tempus ipsum eros, nec semper nulla lobortis quis.</span></p>
<p dir="ltr" class="pt-NormalWeb"><span xml:space="preserve" class="pt-000002"> </span></p>
<p dir="ltr" class="pt-NormalWeb"><span class="pt-DefaultParagraphFont-000001">Nam ultricies ultrices dolor non
viverra. Nam ante odio, porttitor vel cursus a, pellentesque eu turpis. Suspendisse congue sed lacus id
fermentum. Duis lobortis, leo eu blandit egestas, lectus orci aliquet enim, in mattis mauris nibh
vestibulum ipsum. Phasellus lacinia lectus eget libero iaculis euismod. Nunc placerat non mauris eget
sagittis. Fusce rutrum dolor vel leo suscipit iaculis. Aliquam lacinia quam non nisi iaculis
maximus.</span></p>
<p dir="ltr" class="pt-Normal"><span xml:space="preserve" class="pt-000000"> </span></p>
<p dir="ltr" class="pt-NormalWeb"><span class="pt-DefaultParagraphFont-000001">Nam ultricies ultrices dolor non
viverra. Nam ante odio, porttitor vel cursus a, pellentesque eu turpis. Suspendisse congue sed lacus id
fermentum. Duis lobortis, leo eu blandit egestas, lectus orci aliquet enim, in mattis mauris nibh
vestibulum ipsum. Phasellus lacinia lectus eget libero iaculis euismod. Nunc placerat non mauris eget
sagittis. Fusce rutrum dolor vel leo suscipit iaculis. Aliquam lacinia quam non nisi iaculis
maximus.</span></p>
<p dir="ltr" class="pt-NormalWeb"><span class="pt-DefaultParagraphFont-000001">Nam ultricies ultrices dolor non
viverra. Nam ante odio, porttitor vel cursus a, pellentesque eu turpis. Suspendisse congue sed lacus id
fermentum. Duis lobortis, leo eu blandit egestas, lectus orci aliquet enim, in mattis mauris nibh
vestibulum ipsum. Phasellus lacinia lectus eget libero iaculis euismod. Nunc placerat non mauris eget
sagittis. Fusce rutrum dolor vel leo suscipit iaculis. Aliquam lacinia quam non nisi iaculis
maximus.</span></p>
<p dir="ltr" class="pt-Normal"><span xml:space="preserve" class="pt-000000"> </span></p>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you add the value of the `html` parameter to your question (as text, not a screenshot) please? I suspect you may be trying to write plain text rather than a HTML document to the browser, which different browsers may well display differently

Comment: The blank line is just a <p> with an empty <span> inside. I added the raw html in my question. I also suspect the browser behind the windows control (still IE?). In Edge it is displayed correctly.